# Не могу понять в чем ошибка

Tags: c++, циклы

По данному целому числу N распечатайте все квадраты натуральных чисел, не превосходящие N, в порядке возрастания. Формат входных данных Вводится натуральное число. Формат выходных данных Выведите ответ на задачу.

Sample Input: `50`

Sample Output: `1 4 9 16 25 36 49`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int a, b = 1;
  cin >> a;
  while (b <= a) {
        if (float(sqrt(b)) % 1 == 0) {
            cout << b;
        }
        b++;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: По данному целому числу N распечатайте все квадраты натуральных чисел, не превосходящие N, в порядке возрастания.
Формат входных данных
Вводится натуральное число.
Формат выходных данных
Выведите ответ на задачу.
Sample Input:
50
Sample Output:
1 4 9 16 25 36 49

Comment: Это условие программы

Comment: Перенесите текст условия в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что обозначает эта строчка для меня загадка.

> `if (float(sqrt(b)) % 1 == 0) {`

Найти остаток от деления на 1 квадратного корня числа. Что Вы этим хотели сказать? Хотели проверить является ли число целым? Так это делается не так

```
if (1 - floor(sqrt(b)) < 1e-6) {
```

А Ваша задача решается так

```c
int b = 1;
int c = 1;
while (c <= a) {
  cout << c;
  b++;
  c = b * b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В C++ для чисел с плавающей запятой не определен оператор взятия остатка `%`.

Поэтому условие в данном предложении if

```
if (float(sqrt(b)) % 1 == 0) {
```

неверное.

Проще будет записать следующий цикл

```
unsigned int a;

std::cin >> a;

for ( unsigned int i = 1, b; ( b = i * i ) <= a; i++ ) std::cout << b << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```

При этом нет никакой необходимости включать заголовок `cmath` и использовать объявленную в нем функцию `sqrt`.

Программу можно сделать более содержательной. Например,

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): ";

        unsigned int a;

        if ( not ( std::cin >> a ) || a == 0 ) break;

        for ( unsigned int i = 1, b; ( b = i * i ) <= a; i++ ) std::cout << b << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Диалог с программой может выглядеть примерно так

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 100
1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100 
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 50
1 4 9 16 25 36 49 
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 25
1 4 9 16 25 
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, самая большая ошибка - решать вашу задачу методом перебора всех чисел и выяснять, не квадрат ли это число. Лучше идти в другом направлении и выводить поочереждно квадраты, пока они меньше запрошенного `a` (код специально упрощен, чтобы вам было понятнее):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int a,b = 1;
    cin >> a;
    while(b*b <= a)
    {
        cout << b*b << " ";
        ++b;
    }
    cout << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int a,sqr = 1, b = 1;

  cin >> a;
  while (sqr <= a) {
    cout << sqr << " ";
    b++;
    sqr = b * b;;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

вывод:

```
50
1 4 9 16 25 36 49
500
1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100 121 144 169 196 225 256 289 324 361 400 441 484
```

Comment: Я не знаю, кто вам поставил плюсы к ответу, но ваш код неверный.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow спасибо, я понял ошибку и исправился. ты же про sqrt?

Comment: Я про вывод, который получался с использованием sqrt. Но и сейчас исправленная вами программа также будет давать некорректный вывод.

Comment: Вообще-то "квадраты" и "степени двойки" - это "две большие разницы"...